# sed problem for Go templates documentation: Trying to replace "{{ foo.1 }}" with {{"{{"}}foo.1{{"}}"}}

Tags: sed

I'm writing some documentation for the Go template language in Markdown, which has some complexities regarding paired double curly braces. Showing text surrounded by double curly braces requires escaping, since the double curly braces are themselves escapes. So the right pair of curly braces has to be quoted, then enclosed within its own set of curly braces. Same for the left pair. So: For fenced code samples you need to replace

`{{ foo.1 }}`

with

`{{"{{"}}foo.1{{"}}"}}`

I'm almost there. My code works but preserves the original curly braces. I have this so far:

```
echo "{{ foo.1 }} {{ foo.2 }}" | sed -E 's#({{[^}}]*}})#{{"{{"}}\1{{"}}"}}#g'
```

Which results in:

```
{{"{{"}}{{ foo.1 }}{{"}}"}} {{"{{"}}{{ foo.2 }}{{"}}"}}
```

How can I remove the innermost pair of curly braces in the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are awkward with your `sed` expression.

- `[^}}]` is the same as `[^}]` and would match a *single* character that is not a `}`.
- `{` and `}` are special in extended regular expressions (they work like `*` and `+`, i.e., they specify how many times the previous expression needs to match, as in `a{2,4}` to match between 2 and 4 `a`). This means that some `sed` implementations (GNU) would have issues parsing your expression.

---

Here I'm using a basic regular expression with `sed`, and I'm allowing the word within `{{ ... }}` to contain any alphanumeric character whatsoever, and dots (you could possibly change `[[:alnum:].]` to `[^ ]`):

```
$ echo '{{ foo.1 }} {{ foo.2 }}' | sed 's/{{ \([[:alnum:].]*\) }}/{{"{{"}} \1 {{"}}"}}/g'
{{"{{"}} foo.1 {{"}}"}} {{"{{"}} foo.2 {{"}}"}}
```

This would work with both GNU `sed` and BSD `sed` (which I believe you are using).

You will notice that the `sed` expression above is *almost exactly* the same as yours, except that I'm not using an extended regular expression and I have moved the capturing group in to the word within `{{ ... }}` (which is how your remove the innermost curly braces that you get in your result).

Comment: Works a treat! Thank you very much for both the answer and the explanation. I literally had a pounding headache by the time I gave up and posted here. Incredibly grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I get error messages like

> sed: -e expression #1, char 35: Invalid preceding regular expression

if trying your above `sed`. Try instead

```
echo "{{ foo.1 }} {{ foo.2 }}" | sed  's/\({\|}\)\1/{{"&"}}/g'
{{"{{"}} foo.1 {{"}}"}} {{"{{"}} foo.2 {{"}}"}}
```

Comment: Could be because I'm using an ancient version that ships with MacOS. Luckily Kusalananda nailed it. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for giving it a shot.